# In NBG how to prove a $(k+1)$-tuple is a $k$-tuple

Tags: set-theory

Two of GB Keene's books (e.g. "Abstract Sets and Finite Ordinals") state, without proof, the result that every $(k+1)$-tuple is a $k$-tuple.

Keene defines $k$-tuples by iteration of the Kuratowski construction for an ordered pair, so $\{ab\}:=((a),(ab))$, using his notation with curly brackets for ordered pairs and round brackets for 'set'. He goes on to define a $(k+1)$-tuple as an ordered pair $\{rs\}$ where $r$ is an $m$-tuple, $s$ an $n$-tuple with $m+n=k+1$. Some authors make a narrower definition, in which $r$ must be a $1$-tuple.

I'd like to find a proof of Keene's statement  that every $(k+1)$-tuple is also a $k$-tuple, given his wider-than-usual definitions. I know this is probably an easy thing to prove - I just can't seem to find a way through it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Wait, he writes curly braces for ordered pairs and parentheses for sets? That's awful.

Comment: This can't be right. The operation of forming ordered pairs is **not** associative. With the usual Kuratowski definitions, $\{a\} \in (a, (b, c))$ but $\{a\} \not\in ((a, b), c)$ in general. (I am using the round and curly brackets in the standard way and not in the bizarre way that you say GB Keene uses them.)

Comment: PS: I voted against the unexplained and inexplicable downvote: if MSE is not a forum for asking questions about mathematical texts that are hard to understand, what is it for? Duh? Can others please upvote this reasonable question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Kuratovski construction.  What is {a,b,c}? Is it (a, (a, {b,c})=(a, (a, (b, (b,c))))?

Comment: On page 171 of [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm2/fm2122.pdf) Kuratowski actually uses round parentheses where we now use curly braces.  It looks like Keene was just being a little retro with his choice of notation.

Comment: I believe that the n-tuple: {a,b,c,........,x {y,z}} where the last term is itself an ordered pair is, by construction the same thing as the n+1 tuple {a,b,c,.....x,y,z}.  So this follows directly.

Comment: I suggest proceeding by induction on $k$, starting at $k=2$, where the desired result is part of the definition you quoted. For larger $k$, the quoted definition of $(k+1)$-tuple provides two tuples $r$ and $s$, at least one of which will admit an application of the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments, and to Andreas for suggesting the proof by induction. I'd found that same route to a proof myself several hours after posting. The proof is very simple once you get hold of Andreas' idea. I do agree with Noah that Keene's use of {} vs () is unhepful, and I think was the reason I got so stuck with this - I kept intuitively confusing {ab} with the set whose members are a and b, whereas in Keene's notation that set is (ab).

Comment: Rob - you commented on the non-associativity of ordered pair formation. I'm not sure I understand the point - I've not detected any associativity issues in the way Keene defines these things. One important point here in his development is that (for example, and in his notation) {{ab}{c}} and {{a}{bc}} are both valid but different 3-tuples constructed from a,b and c. The latter he defines to be a 'normal tuple', in general a normal n-tuple being of the form {rs} where r is a 1-tuple. It's the latter he uses to define natural numbers from the null set in the usual way.

Comment: I am truly confused by the fact this post was closed and then put on hold, for reasons I cannot fathom. This was my first post, ever. No one likes to be rebuffed, and I will certainly hesitate before I post a new question here again. I am however both impressed and grateful for the rapid and helpful comments that were made here, over night in my time zone.

Comment: Yes, the closure is deeply mysterious. The reason given is the one that is usually used for questions that just consist of a homework exercise copied word-for-word without any comments by the asker -- but this question is not even remotely like that.

Comment: As for the question itself, does the book give any particular meaning to an $1$-tuple to start the recursion with? The definition given here seems to be strange in that (in standard notation) $((a,b),(c,d))$ is a $3$-tuple in two different ways, so it is not clear whether the three elements are $(a,b)$ and $c$ and $d$, or or on the other hand $a$ and $b$ and $(c,d)$.

Comment: @Mbirchtree: $(a, (b, c)) \neq ((a, b), c)$ when we use the standard definition of ordered pairs. Keene's statement as you originally quoted it contradicts this. What you say in your comment about "valid but different $n$-tuples" suggests that Keene is aware of this and is working really hard to confuse his or her readers, but as I don't have the book to hand, I can't say for certain.

Comment: Hemming, that's interesting. Ah well, I got the answer I needed to my question, for which I'm grateful. But this experience is overall a deterrent for me regarding future use.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: $((a, b), (c, d))$ is not a 3-tuple in any standard sense: it's a pair (2-tuple) whose elements are also pairs.

Comment: @RobArthan: Right -- but I'm not talking about the standard sense, but according to the non-standard definition quoted in the question here: _"He goes on to define a (k+1)-tuple as an ordered pair {rs} where r is an m-tuple, s an n-tuple with m+n=k+1"_

Comment: @HenningMakholm: fair enough.Describing $((a, b), (c, d))$ as a 3-tuple made me shudder, but that does seem to be the terminology used in the OP's book.

Comment: Henning & Rob - thx for your interest in my question. I should give something back. Here's an outline of the proof by induction, in Keene's notation. Separately, I'll give you my views of Keene's choice of notation. So proof in outline. A 1-tuple is defined as {b}:=b where b is any set. Since a 2-tuple {ab} where a,b are any sets is defined as the set ((a),(a,b)), it follows that the 1-tuple {{ab}} is {ab}, hence a 2-tuple is also a 1-tuple. For a (k+1)-tuple {rs} with s an m-tuple, {rs} will be a k-tuple if s is an (m-1)-tuple. But m<k+1, so the result follows by induction.

Comment: On Keene's book: it's a detailed account of the route to the definition of numbers from the Bernays axioms for set theory. The chapter I've been quoting from is an introductory chapter. I've not read the rest of the book, where he gets to the detail. But I have skimmed it, and I note that he moves in tiny steps - e.g. he proves as a theorem that for any set c there exists a set for which c is the only member. By the end of the book, n-tuplets are established in the form we know and love. The 'strange' definitions I've quoted are needed en route before that familiar territory can be reached.

Comment: Since I think the question never was missing context, I cast the last vote to reopen it. As it is now reopened, it would be nice if somebody posts an answer. If @AndreasBlass doesn't feel like converting his comment into an answer, how about you, Mbirchtree, post an answer? I'm sorry about the bad experience you had here, but mistakes happen, and as long as they can be rectified, one can live with that.

Comment: On his notation. He's a logician writing in 1961 for mathematicians. I don't know if that explains {} vs (). I do see that within the book there is sense to his choice. He starts with the basic rules of logic and inference, and uses mostly natural language to explain himself, using round brackets as in examples like "(Mozart was a composer) and (Greeks like cheese)". He develops the concept of set & predicate in that material, and () move naturally from English into the notation for a set. If in written English we used [ and ], then I guess they would have been his chosen notation for sets.

Comment: @DanielFischer: many thanks for that. Does the comment I posted before yours provide enough of a proof, or would you say I should detail it more.

Comment: I think you should flesh it out some more. You don't need to give the full details, but a bit more than in that comment.

Comment: Ok, will do once I work out how the editor works on this system.